# Angular routing/switch components without page reload

Tags: angular, angular-router

This is a very basic setup of what i have,

```
<app-header></app-header>
<app-search></app-search>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

and inside the router-outlet i have a search-result componet and a user component

like such

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'search', component: SearchResultComponent },
    { path: 'user', component: UserComponent}
];
```

Im using router, routermodule from angular core, and have search result and user inside it, with path search and user

If possible i want to skip path all together, and once i search for something in the app-search and hit enter, and once i get a response from the server, 
the router-outlet will just show the search-result component without reloading the page

Comment: I think you need to read up a bit more on how routing works. Nesting components inside a router-outlet is not how it works..

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote here is an antipattern:

```
<router-outlet>
  <search-result></search-result>
  <user></user>
</router-outlet>
```

The [RouterOutlet](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet) directive is not meant to contain anything. It's just a placeholder for route-loaded components.

If you want to achieve this, you have to define routes. The `SearchComponent` would trigger, let's say `this.router.navigate(['search'], { queryParams: { query: 'what your used typed' } });`

Then define a route to the `SearchResultComponent`: `{ path: 'search', component: SearchResultComponent }`

Finally, in the `SearchResultComponent`, subscribe to the queryParams and send a request (considering you have a `SearchService` with a `search` method:

```
this.activatedRoute.queryParams
    .pipe(switchMap(params => this.searchService.search(params['query'])))
    .subscribe(result => this.result = result);
```

Comment: Sorry what i meant with my code is that I do have the search result and user inside the router component with a path, but i would rather skip the path and just switch the components in and out depending on what kind of request i do and what type of response i get

Comment: To do that, use ngif based on the inbound route. Only show one thing at a time. There are other ways too like rendering both with one outside view range to be brought into view when needed.